# Relative wants to visit me in UK from Pakistan, does he need supporting documents from me?

Tags: pakistani-citizens, uk-residents

I need to know if there are any supporting documents that I should provide him.

He is a well-off businessman and will be supporting himself (and his partner) on his stay. He has asked me if I can provide a supporting letter, but having read the latest guidance on the UK gov site I'm not sure if he actually needs this anymore. He hasn't asked me for anything other than a letter, and hasn't made it clear if he will actually stay with me.

I'm a UK citizen and I have my own accommodation here.

Comment: He doesn’t really need one. You said he is well off that means he should try to convince the ECO on his own that he can afford the trip easily and does not have any reason to overstay in the U.K.  He does not need a support letter but there is no harm in him stating that he has relatives in the UK he will meet on the trip.

Comment: Yep, pretty much what I've found while googling for the latest info about supporting documents for a visitor, looks like they did away with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are going to be providing him with support, financial or otherwise, then there is no need to provide supporting documents, especially financial documents. Providing unnecessary documents can show a lack of understanding of the visa process, which will hurt the application. On the other hand, anything that adds credibility to an application can be helpful.

If your relative is staying with you, then a letter stating that you will be giving him accommodation (and ideally some evidence showing that you can provide it) would be helpful. If his stated reason for coming to the UK is to visit you, then if he is able to show that you exist, that you are related to him, and that you are in the UK legally (i.e. a citizen) will also help his case.

Comment: Thanks, that confirms a lot of what I was reading elsewhere

Comment: @Anonymous Person Your relative must answer the question about whether he has family in the UK truthfully regardless of whether he is funding everything himself or visiting you, or not.